# HTTP Error 503 in Django on heroku app

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm using **Django** and i'm trying to run this lib '**translate**' or '**goslate**' so I can translate text from google translate in runtime and free.
for goslate:
this is my function

```
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()
translate = gs.translate(txt,target,source)
```

when I work locally it's working great and I'm getting the translation for the given 'txt' 
I deploy my django app to herokuapp.com I got an error
this is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goslate.py", line 409, in translate
    return _unwrapper_single_element(self._translate_single_text(text, target_language, source_language))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goslate.py", line 334, in _translate_single_text
    results = list(self._execute(make_task(i) for i in split_text(text)))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goslate.py", line 203, in _execute
    yield each()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goslate.py", line 332, in <lambda>
    return lambda: self._basic_translate(text, target_language, source_lauguage)[0]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goslate.py", line 251, in _basic_translate
    response_content = self._open_url(url)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/goslate.py", line 181, in _open_url
    response = self._opener.open(request, timeout=self._TIMEOUT)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 469, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 656, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

why locally it's working great and on heroku it's not? how can I fix it?
or a new translation lib that it's free

Comment: everywhere you (your ip-address) have some limit - words/day free usage ... try locally - how many words you can translate per day

Comment: there isn't a limit, it's not use the regular api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem,
google translate block the request from heroku
i need to use proxy server so google translate will not think that i'm a robot
there is an free app that i found in heroku named "fixie" i think it will do the trick